# C#/Unity Camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

Im trying to make it so that the camera always follows the ball, but i can only rotate it when i hold down rightclick. although, right now, it only follows the ball when i hold right click aswell. Is there a way to seperate the two?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Orbit2 : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;

private Rigidbody rigidbody;

float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;

    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody != null)
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (target
        && Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
        {
            distance -= hit.distance;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
}
```

Comment: you may want to revise your question : currently you say it should happen when "rightclick is down"  and that you want it when "rightclick is down"

Comment: Thats because i do want it to happen when i hold rightclick down. so im not quite sure what you mean by that question...

Comment: I only want the rotation to happen when i hold it down, not the camera movement, i want that to stay permanent.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the rotation to happen only when the right mouse button is held down. If this is true, then remove `Input.GetMouseButton(1)` from where it is now and then wrap it around `transform.rotation = rotation;`. It is as simple as that. FYI, you don't even need `if (target)`. That is unnecessary but I leave it as it is.

```
public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;

private Rigidbody rigidbody;

float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;

    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody != null)
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (target)
    {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
        {
            distance -= hit.distance;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

        //Move Input.GetMouseButton(1) here
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            transform.rotation = rotation;
        }
        transform.position = position;
    }
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: Well, it worked. sorta. it now does follow the ball when im not using rightclick, but the problem is now that when im not using  the right mouse button, the screen does still move relative to where i hold the mouse. ill upload a video real quick of what i mean. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaesOfRcR4k